# Adding text to fading in and fading out images

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I want to add text to the images that are fading in and fading out. And I want the text to fade in and out with the concerned image. Any Idea how can this be done? Thanks in advance! I have given the code below:

```
<html>  
<div id="fadeslide">
            <img src="9.jpg" class="is-showing"/>
            <img src="10.jpg"/>
            <img src="11.jpg"/>
            <img src="12.jpg"/>
            <img src="13.jpg"/> 
</div>
</html>



<script>
function slideShow() {

    var showing = $('#fadeslide .is-showing');  

    var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next(): 

showing.parent().children(':first');    

    showing.fadeOut(1000, function() { 

        next.fadeIn(1000).addClass('is-showing');

    }).removeClass('is-showing');

setTimeout(slideShow, 5500);

    }

$(document).ready(function() {

    slideShow();

});

</script>


#fadeslide {
    width: 960px;
    height: 640px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#fadeslide img {
    display: none;
}

#fadeslide .is-showing {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```css
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="https://wallpapers.pub/web/wallpapers/birds-water-spray-wallpaper/3840x2160.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Ok try it**

```css
   body, html {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 90px;
        font-family: Poiret One;
        height: 100%;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #723362, #9d223c);
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #723362, #9d223c);
        overflow: hidden;
        color: white;
    }
 
    .letter {
        position: relative;
        top: -webkit-calc(50% - 60px);
        top: calc(50% - 60px);
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 200ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 200ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 400ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 400ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 600ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 600ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(4) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 800ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 800ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(5) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 1000ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 1000ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(6) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 1200ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 1200ms;
    }
    .letter:nth-child(7) {
        -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite 1400ms;
        animation: fade 4s infinite 1400ms;
    }
 
    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
        50% {
            opacity: 0.02;
        }
    }
 
    @keyframes fade {
        50% {
            opacity: 0.02;
        }
    }
```

```html
<span class='letter'>L</span>
<span class='letter'>O</span>
<span class='letter'>A</span>
<span class='letter'>D</span>
<span class='letter'>I</span>
<span class='letter'>N</span>
<span class='letter'>G</span>
```

**or this**

```css
.fadebutton {
text-align:center;
padding:20px 20px;
background:#fff;
line-height:60px;
transition: opacity 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
-o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all ease 0.5s ;
transition: all ease 0.5s ;
border:1px solid #ff3000;
border-radius:5px;
}
 
.fadebutton:hover {
background-image:url("http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg");
color:#fff;
-webkit-transition: all ease 0.7s;
-moz-transition: all ease 0.7s;
-o-transition: all ease 0.7s;
-ms-transition: all ease 0.7s ;
transition: all ease 0.5s ;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadebutton">HOVER YOUR MOUSE CURSOR HERE!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Razia. But I actually want some text on the pictures which would fade in and out with the image. How can I do that?